# How to share Product Details from website to Facebook and LinkedIn

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

I need to share my product details (Name, Image, and Description) from my website to Facebook and LinkedIn but not showing anything in FB but the URL is passing with all parameters. My Code as Follows

```
@foreach ($data['products'] as $list)
<img src="{{ $list['oneimage'] }}" alt="">
@endforeach
@foreach ($data['products'] as $list)
{{ $list['name'] }}
{{ $list['description'] }}
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{url('/Shop/'.$data['webname'].'/products/'.$list['id'].'/details')}}&summary={{$data['webname']}}&og:image={{$list['oneimage']}}" target="_blank">
    </a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{url('/Shop/'.$data['webname'].'/products/'.$list['id'].'/details')}}&title={{$data['webname']}}&summary={{$data['webname']}}" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: AMC I need to share product image, name, and description to social media from my webiste

Comment: What is the issue, though?

Comment: AMC if I try to sharing, product name, image, and description noting will coming in the social media

Answer (score 0):

Your URL format is correct...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

So, all you need to set now is the `og:` tags to indicate things like title, summary, image, etc..  These tags will be inserted into the `<head>` block of your HTML...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/1234567.jpg'/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article' />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Share Documentation: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

If you want to check and see if you did everything right, then look at the  **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**.  Everything from plain old `<title>` tags to `oEmbed` and `og:` tags will be inspected and tested and the results given to the user shown.  Here's a small little demo site I put together that uses the above code: [EarthFluent.com](https://www.earthfluent.com/).